# Clang-format BlockIndent option but for braces

Tags: c++, clang, clang-format

I was trying to configure my `.clang-format` file to satisfy my needs, and came pretty close. However, I haven't figure out how to deal with formatting like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> {
    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
    "cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc"};
```

To make them look like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> v {
    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
    "cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc"
};
```

I find it much easier to read.

I was sitting on `https://clang-format-configurator.site/` for 2 hours trying to configure formatting options and haven't achieved what I was expecting to.

I am not a native English speaker, so sorry for mistakes I may make and don't blame me for this, please.

UPD: here is my `.clang-format` file:

```
---
BasedOnStyle: Google
AccessModifierOffset: -4
AlignAfterOpenBracket: BlockIndent
AlignArrayOfStructures: None
AlignConsecutiveAssignments:
  Enabled: false
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments: false
  AlignCompound: false
  PadOperators: true
AlignConsecutiveBitFields:
  Enabled: false
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments: false
  AlignCompound: false
  PadOperators: false
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations:
  Enabled: false
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments: false
  AlignCompound: false
  PadOperators: false
AlignConsecutiveMacros:
  Enabled: false
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments: false
  AlignCompound: false
  PadOperators: false
AlignEscapedNewlines: DontAlign
AlignOperands: Align
AlignTrailingComments:
  Kind: Always
  OverEmptyLines: 0
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Always
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: AllIfsAndElse
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: true
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: true
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: Yes
BinPackArguments: true
BinPackParameters: true
BitFieldColonSpacing: Both
BraceWrapping:
  AfterCaseLabel: false
  AfterClass: false
  AfterControlStatement: Never
  AfterEnum: false
  AfterFunction: false
  AfterNamespace: false
  AfterObjCDeclaration: false
  AfterStruct: false
  AfterUnion: false
  AfterExternBlock: false
  BeforeCatch: false
  BeforeElse: false
  BeforeLambdaBody: false
  BeforeWhile: false
  IndentBraces: false
  SplitEmptyFunction: true
  SplitEmptyRecord: true
  SplitEmptyNamespace: true
BreakAfterAttributes: Never
BreakAfterJavaFieldAnnotations: false
BreakArrays: true
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BraceWrapping:
  AfterFunction: false
  AfterControlStatement: false
  AfterEnum: false
  AfterStruct: false
  SplitEmptyFunction: false
  SplitEmptyRecord: false
  SplitEmptyNamespace: false
  AfterNamespace: false
  AfterObjCDeclaration: false
  AfterObjCProtocol: false
  AfterBlock: true
  AfterClass: false
  AfterExternBlock: false
  BeforeCatch: false
  BeforeElse: false
  BeforeLambdaBody: false
  BeforeWhile: false
BreakBeforeConceptDeclarations: Always
BreakBeforeInlineASMColon: OnlyMultiline
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeColon
BreakInheritanceList: BeforeColon
BreakStringLiterals: true
ColumnLimit: 80
CommentPragmas: ""
CompactNamespaces: false
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 0
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
DerivePointerAlignment: true
DisableFormat: false
EmptyLineAfterAccessModifier: Never
EmptyLineBeforeAccessModifier: LogicalBlock
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
FixNamespaceComments: true
IncludeBlocks: Regroup
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex: ^<.*\.h>
    Priority: 1
    SortPriority: 0
    CaseSensitive: false
  - Regex: ^<.*
    Priority: 2
    SortPriority: 0
    CaseSensitive: false
  - Regex: .*
    Priority: 3
    SortPriority: 0
    CaseSensitive: false
IncludeIsMainRegex: ([-_](test|unittest))?$
IncludeIsMainSourceRegex: ""
IndentAccessModifiers: false
IndentCaseBlocks: false
IndentCaseLabels: false
IndentExternBlock: AfterExternBlock
IndentGotoLabels: false
IndentPPDirectives: None
IndentRequiresClause: true
IndentWidth: 4
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false
InsertBraces: false
InsertNewlineAtEOF: false
InsertTrailingCommas: None
IntegerLiteralSeparator:
  Binary: 0
  BinaryMinDigits: 0
  Decimal: 0
  DecimalMinDigits: 0
  Hex: 0
  HexMinDigits: 0
JavaScriptQuotes: Leave
JavaScriptWrapImports: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
LambdaBodyIndentation: Signature
Language: Cpp
LineEnding: LF
MacroBlockBegin: ""
MacroBlockEnd: ""
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: None
ObjCBinPackProtocolList: Never
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 2
ObjCBreakBeforeNestedBlockParam: true
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: false
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: true
PPIndentWidth: -1
PackConstructorInitializers: NextLine
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 2
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 1
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyBreakOpenParenthesis: 0
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyBreakTemplateDeclaration: 10
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyIndentedWhitespace: 0
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 200
PointerAlignment: Left
QualifierAlignment: Leave
ReferenceAlignment: Pointer
ReflowComments: true
RemoveBracesLLVM: true
RemoveSemicolon: false
RequiresClausePosition: OwnLine
RequiresExpressionIndentation: OuterScope
SeparateDefinitionBlocks: Leave
ShortNamespaceLines: 1
SortIncludes: CaseSensitive
SortJavaStaticImport: Before
SortUsingDeclarations: LexicographicNumeric
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceAfterLogicalNot: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: true
SpaceAroundPointerQualifiers: Default
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCaseColon: false
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: true
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: true
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceBeforeParensOptions:
  AfterControlStatements: true
  AfterForeachMacros: true
  AfterFunctionDeclarationName: false
  AfterFunctionDefinitionName: false
  AfterIfMacros: true
  AfterOverloadedOperator: false
  AfterRequiresInClause: false
  AfterRequiresInExpression: false
  BeforeNonEmptyParentheses: false
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: true
SpaceBeforeSquareBrackets: false
SpaceInEmptyBlock: false
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
SpacesInAngles: Never
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInConditionalStatement: false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
SpacesInLineCommentPrefix:
  Minimum: 1
  Maximum: -1
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
Standard: c++17
TabWidth: 4
UseTab: Never
DeriveLineEnding: false
```

Comment: What does your .clang-format file contain?